# Runtime Error 13 Mismatch Type When Referring to Opened File using Dialog Box

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dialog

Hello kind computer programmers!

I have written a loop to pull out specific cells from a source file and move them into a destination file in a different orientation.  I want the source file to be selectable using a dialog box and once it's been opened, I want to reference that file in the loop (called Gen5Output).  I have tried globally designating Gen5Output as a string and then referencing in the:

WS_Count = Workbooks(Gen5Output).Worksheets.Count

line but I get a mismatch error on that line which I am assuming is because I can't use a string in WS_Count? I'm not sure how else to refer to the file I opened in the first sub.  I am very very new to VBA so please be kind and explain in laymans terms if possible.

Thank you!!

```
   Option Base 1
Public Gen5Output As String

Sub OpenNewBox()
'select source file
Dim xObjFD As FileDialog
Set xObjFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  With xObjFD
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb", 1
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Gen5Output = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Workbooks.Open Gen5Output
    
End Sub

Sub WorksheetLoop()

         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim Q As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook.
         WS_Count = Workbooks(Gen5Output).Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
         For Q = 1 To WS_Count
                    Dim I, j, k, m As Integer
                    Dim mean(34) As Double
                    Dim SD(34) As Double
                    
                    j = 0
                    k = 83
                    
                    For I = 1 To 32
                    j = j + 3
                    mean(I) = Gen5Output.Worksheets(Q).Cells(k, j)
                    SD(I) = Workbooks("210730EB_SampleDataSource.xlsm").Worksheets(Q).Cells(k + 1, j)
                    Next I
                    
                    
                    m = 1
                    For I = 1 To 32
                    Workbooks("210726EB_BiologEcoplatesTestingData.xlsm").Worksheets("Absorbance Mean Values").Cells(3, m + 7) = mean(I)
                    Workbooks("210726EB_BiologEcoplatesTestingData.xlsm").Worksheets("Absorbance Mean Values").Cells(3, m + 8) = SD(I)
                    m = m + 2
                    Next I
            ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
            ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
            MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Q).Name

         Next Q







End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Gen5Output` is the full path, but `Workbooks()` wants only the file name.

I'd avoid the global variable and have `OpenNewBox` return a workbook object:

```vb
'select and return source file or Nothing if no file selected
Function OpenNewBox() As Workbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb", 1
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Set OpenNewBox = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems.Item(1))
        Else
            Set OpenNewBox = Nothing
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Then you can do something like:

```vb
Sub WorksheetLoop()

    Dim wbInput As Workbook
    '...
    '...
    
    Set wbInput = OpenNewBox()          'user selects a file
    If wbInput Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no file was chosen

    '...etc etc using wbInput
```